# How to run Sharepoint on Phonegap?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, mobile

I am very new to sharepoint so need your help in getting started.
I am working for an NGO and they have a bit of a weird requirement. they want a sharepoint website whose content creation is as easy as creating word document with sections but when displaying on mobile devices it should behave as a mobile app.

Example:

one document has a long table with person profiles .

On mobile phonegap application it should be searchable and each page person should have a dedicated page. so we will have Image on top with Name and scrollable text below

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

ok, before responding - that type of requirement is what fails projects in the 1st place. I agree most people hate the UX on SharePoint, but starting to replace quite some awesome features is not the way to go. ask for specifics.

Now to your question - my read "page with people profiles, searchable, with a certain look & feel". best approach, to my sense would be - assuming you have Search + User Profiles connection + synchronization up and running (no need for My sites though, just to be clear). In lack of details, I assume here 2013 - so the way to go would be (PhoneGAP interacts via WS calls, e.g. REST mostly):

- Challenge no.1 - authentication. You need to use JSOM or REST calls (unless you build an ASP.NET solution in which case the CSOM would work too) - to understand your options start here http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj164060.aspx. But specifically for PhoneGap your code is totally executing outside of SharePoint's context - so check at http://allthatjs.com/2012/04/03/using-sharepoint-csom-in-html5-apps/ or -
- Challenge no. 2 - understanding what you're looking for, e.g. Search REST API to get the most varied search results (NOT only from the People vertical, could be documents, etc.). One example would be http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/01/calling-sharepoint-search-using-rest-eg.html or for People you could also use the People API (e.g. SP.UserProfiles.js - example http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/02/sharepoint-2013-working-with-user.html)
- Challenge no. 3 - build effective queries on your UI

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint has some simple Mobile Views, but all they do is minimalize the UI a bit.
The UX you describe requires custom development.

SharePoint is your datastore, (*but could be any other datastore*)

The areas you have to master

- Manage the datastore
- Get access to the datastore

  - Read from the datastore
  - Write to the datastore
- Present information

There is no best way of doing this as it mainly relies on what you know (or want to learn)

Furthermore, your client does not have a *weird* requirement; they just want a different UX (on top of existing SharePoint functionality)

Areas of expertise you (may) have to Learn:

- HTML/CSS/JS
- SharePoint Content Types
- SharePoint Page Templates
- SharePoint Display Templates (CSR, JSlink)
- SharePoint Search (API)
- SharePoint API (JSOM & REST)
- AZURE
- ADAL
- ...
- ...

Google is your best friend learning these, "[SharePoint and PhoneGap](https://www.google.nl/search?q=sharepoint+phonegap&oq=sharepoint+phonegap)" gives you plenty of leads.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**: Use Microsoft PowerApps (probably easiest way but not free as licence is required for every user).

**Option 2**: Use SharePoint REST API to connect to SharePoint from client.